# Rule Requiring Quote Line Item Based on Another field in quote object

Tags: validation-rule, quote, quotelineitem

i was trying to write a validation rule for a field (Partner) in that field if verizon is entered and it should select only product related to verizon in quote line editor can anyone help me with a validation for this

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No was confused how to approach this issue

Comment: Not (CONTAINS( SBQQ__Partner__c , 'Verizon - HQ') ) && ISCHANGED( Roll_Up_of_Verizon__c )

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `Lookup Filter`.

> #### [Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en)
>
> Improve user productivity and data quality with lookup filters. Lookup filters are administrator settings that restrict the valid values and lookup dialog results for lookup, master-detail, and hierarchical relationship fields.
>
> ---
>
> Administrators specify the restrictions by configuring filter criteria that compare fields and values on:
>
> - The current record (source)
> - The lookup object (target)
> - The user's record, permissions, and role
> - Records directly related to the target object
>
> For example, you can:
>
> - Restrict the `Account Name` field on opportunities to allow only accounts with a record type of Customer, filtering out Partner and Competitor.
> - Restrict the `Account Name` field on opportunities to allow only active accounts.
> - Restrict the `Contact` field on cases to allow only contacts associated with the account specified in the `Account Name` field on the case record.
> - Restrict the `Account Name` field on cases to allow only users with the “International Sales” profile to create or edit cases for accounts outside the United States.
>
> ---
>
> Administrators can make lookup filters required or optional.
>
> - For fields with required lookup filters, only values that match the lookup filter criteria appear in the lookup dialog. Also, users can't save invalid values manually typed in the field when editing the record. If a user tries to save an invalid value, Salesforce displays an error message, which administrators can customize.
> - For fields with optional lookup filters, only values that match the lookup filter criteria appear in the lookup dialog initially; however, users can click the Show all results link in the lookup dialog to remove the filter and view all search result values for the lookup field. Also, optional lookup filters allow users to save values that don't match the lookup filter criteria, and Salesforce does not display an error message if a user tries to save such values.

---

#### Related Reading

- **[Define Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm)**
- **[Lookup Filter Examples](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_examples.htm)**
- **[Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en)** (referenced above)
- **[Notes on Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&language=en)**